# how to pass the parameter in AJAX data in this condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here i am using AJAX ,I am passing like this `url:"http://www.domain.com/api/get/searchProperties?area="+area+"&city="+city+"&listingType="+listing_type,` URL means it is working fine, but i want to pass data so i am trying like this `data = 'area='+ area  + '&city='+ city + '&listingType='+ listing_type;`,now i am getting error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    //url:"www.domain.com/api/get/searchProperties?area=Marathahalli&city=Bangalore&listingType=RENT",// this working
      url:"http://www.domain.com/api/get/searchProperties?"
      data = 'area='+ area  + '&city='+ city + '&listingType='+ listing_type;
         success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); // Suucess
      },
    error:function(exception){
    console.log('Exeption:'+exception);
   }
   }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the data property in the ajax object?

Comment: Yes,but i am not able to pass

Comment: Then this is `data =` not a right syntax. You have to use `data :`. Also you have to use `,` at the end instead of ";"

Comment: @charlietfl Using `data =` inside an object is a wrong syntax. I meant that.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $.ajax({
                 type:'GET',
                    //url:"www.domain.com/api/get/searchProperties?area=Marathahalli&city=Bangalore&listingType=RENT",// this working
                      url:"http://www.domain.com/api/get/searchProperties?",
                      data :{ area: area,
                             city:city,
                             listingType: listing_type
                      },
                     dataType:"JSON",
                      success: function(data) {
                      console.log(data); // Suucess
                   },
                    error:function(exception){
                        console.log('Exeption:'+exception);
                   }
                }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

dont forget that `$.ajax({})` which have `{}` that means you need to provide an object which fulfilled the parameter like [Jquery Ajax Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) , because object format is  `{key1:value, key2: value2, key3: value3}` that means you must use `data:` instead of `data=` and each `key:value` pair must be separated by comas `,`.

Comment: I am tried your code but it going to error function

Comment: hmm, what is your datatype returned from the url? is it on json format? if not you can change it to html or text

Comment: hmm, what is your datatype returned from the url? is it on json format? if not you can change dataType:"json" into dataType:"html" or dataType:"text" dont forget there are comas after it like dataType:"json",

Comment: Ya i got, please i have one doubt solve this also,which are the parameter not empty that only i want to pass ,suppose one filed (city) is empty means  i don't want to pass that parameter how can do this

Comment: the data's value: {area: area,
                             city:city,
                             listingType: listing_type} is an array... sooo you can specify an array which you have parameters that you want to pass on ajax example: if you have specified an array with the value you want to pass in a variable named getValue={ area: area,
                             listingType: listing_type
                      }; then you can just data:getValue

Comment: Can u please update your anser possible means make it fiddle

Comment: @SagunthalaK What is the error that you are receiving from server?

Comment: @SagunthalaK Sounds like an error from the server side. Check your code there.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you close off the previous statements with `;`.

Comment: semi colons are optional in javascript and OP problem has nothing to do with missing ones